# Merging all the colunms in R with colunm names

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following data

```
> df
X1  X2  X3 
1   3   4  
1   0   0  
1   1   0
```

and I want to merge all the column so that the final output will be

```
new colName
1     X1
1     X1
1     X1
3     X2
0     X2
1     X2
4     X3
0     X3
0     X3
```

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, everything(), names_to = 'colName', values_to = 'new')`

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `stack`

```
> setNames(stack(df),c("new","colName"))
  new colName
1   1      X1
2   1      X1
3   1      X1
4   3      X2
5   0      X2
6   1      X2
7   4      X3
8   0      X3
9   0      X3
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(X1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), X2 = c(3L, 0L, 1L), X3 = c(4L, 
0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library (tidyverse)



pivot_longer(df,X1:X3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try gathering the column names with `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)

X1 <- c(1,1,1)
X2 <- c(3,0,1)
X3 <- c(4,0,0)

df <- data.frame(X1, X2, X3)

df <- df %>%
  gather(new, colname, X1, X2, X3)

print(df)

  new colname
1  X1       1
2  X1       1
3  X1       1
4  X2       3
5  X2       0
6  X2       1
7  X3       4
8  X3       0
9  X3       0
```